# Using a column in jqGrid to execute a jQuery AJAX function

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I've been searching the web and can't seem to find an example of how to call a jQuery AJAX function with the data selected from a row (via a button or link on the same row).

Can someone please either point me to a link or provide a code snippet on how to do this?

Comment: Ok.. Well, I found out that I could use the "onCellSelect" event and then use that event to execute the "getRowData" method to retrieve the data in that row. Inside the "onCellSelect" event, I would imagine I would then need to call my AJAX function passing it the row data.

Comment: @sagesky36: You don't posted enough details about what you do (for example which `datatype` you use) and in what moment you need to send the data of selected row. Depend on the details the best place for the Ajax call would be `onSelectRow`, `beforeSelectRow` or `onCellSelect`. Depend on the option which you use the best choice to get the data from selected row would be `getLocalRow` or `getRowData` (or `getCell`). In any way you should call `jQuery.ajax` yourself inside of corresponding callback.